# How do I escape a character in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I have an XSLT that transforms a XML to PLSQL

I need to escape the character: >  (greater than)

ex:

```
P_C710_INT_PROFILE_ID =>
```

I tried using `&gt;` and putting the character in xsl:text with no luck

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the attribute `method` in `xsl:output`? What is the output that you get when you use `&gt;`?

Comment: I use  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

The output I get is '&gt;'

Comment: Then it should work. Add the rule of your XSLT to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank everyone but the correct answer is this:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: @user412045: This is wrong. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Text-Output-Method *"The text output method ignores the disable-output-escaping attribute, since it does not perform any output escaping"*

Comment: Well nothing else works for me, do you have a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem. This stylesheet (empty):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<text>P_C710_INT_PROFILE_ID =&gt;</text>
```

Output:

```
P_C710_INT_PROFILE_ID =>
```

**EDIT**: Because your question is not clear, I'm adding a solution in case you want to output character entity under a xsl:output/@method="text" declaration.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()" name="text">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="$text != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring($text,1,1)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$first = '&gt;'">&amp;gt;</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="text">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text,2,(string-length($text)-1) div 2 + 1)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="text">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text,(string-length($text)-1) div 2 + 3)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
P_C710_INT_PROFILE_ID =&gt;
```

This relate to [Render escaped XML on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289871/render-escaped-xml-on-browser/3290631)

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well and even after changing the output method and adding the disable-output-escaping attribute and it still wasnt working.

Then i looked in my source code and i realized that i was using an XmlTextWriter with the results of the transform and the XmlTextWriter was applying the output escaping. Once i switched it to just use a StringWriter the output was correct.