# Sharepoint 2007 / Jquery - Replace all text on body or render HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Looking to get some advice here. I have a SharePoint 2007 with a very basic page using XSLT and the issue I have is when the data is displayed I get a lot of these characters `&lt;&gt;()&quot;&#39;&amp;` These are equivalent to  `<>()"'*<>&` for some reason SharePoint dosent like those characters even after I escape the characters.

Ive decided to go with a Jquery approach instead, i read threads on the web on how to replace certain text but couldnt find anything for multiple texts. Ive also read that jquery has a away to render HTML using .parseHTML. Im looking to get some advice on what would be the best way to fix those characters?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out `disable-output-escaping` as mentioned in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415728/how-do-i-escape-a-character-in-xslt) It might work for your situation.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried setting the disable-output-escaping to yes and no but makes no difference. <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="ddwrt:AutoNewLine(string(@Notes))" />

Comment: My XSLT knowledge has dried out, sorry. I used to do a ton of SharePoint 2007 work about 7 - 8 years ago, but I've forgotten most of it. Using XSLT for outputting data was a PITA, so I feel your pain :)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately were stuck trying to support it, it's been a pain supporting this old environment. If ever you have other suggestions let me know.